# Convert db_query in EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 8, database

I have the following query, which works.

```
  $email = db_query('
    Select u.init as email 
    FROM user__roles as r 
    JOIN users_field_data as u ON r.entity_id = u.uid 
    WHERE u.status = 1 
      AND r.roles_target_id = :role
  ', array('role' => 'pubblisher'))->fetchAll();
```

I want to convert it to use `EntityFieldQuery`, but I didn't find any Join function in [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/interface/QueryInterface/8). How do I convert my code to use `EntityFieldQuery`?

Comment: To my knowledge neither Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 entity field queries support Joins out of the box.

Comment: @tenken thanks. So if I want a Join I have to use db_query ? Im not expert of d7

Comment: hmmm maybe not, while there is no Join() function you may be able to achieve it using sub-entities. See: https://www.drupal.org/node/1882418

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only query for fields, entity query does the joins automatically for you.

Note that entity query can only return entity ID's, you then need to load them.

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('roles', 'pubblisher')
  ->execute();

$users = User::loadMultiple($ids);
```

Comment: Active / blocked for users still use literals and not constants in Drupal 8?

Comment: Apparently, I couldn't find a constant for it. If you have a user entity, then you can use isActive()/isBlocked().

Comment: nice, What is the difference between EntityFieldQuery and entityQuery ? When I Want to retrieve only field of the same entity i use EFQ instead when I have to create join I have to use entityQuery ? Thanks

Comment: EntityFieldQuery is how it is called in D7, it doesn't exist in D8. It's the same thing, more or less, just a different name.